# How can I get Powershell to generate logs after moving files?

Tags: powershell, logging

Hi this is the first time I create a program using powershell, I created a powershell script to move old files that are not in use to a NAS, the code works as what I want, but I need a Log.txt file for find out what files have been moved. can someone please help me?

```
$Date = Get-Date -UFormat %d-%m-%Y
$Source = 'C:\Source\'
$Temp = 'C:\Backup-Temp\'
$Nas = 'D:\Destination\'
$Ext = "*.zip","*.rar"
$SetTime = '-5'

New-Item -Path $Temp -Name "Backup-$Date" -ItemType "directory"

Foreach ($Ext in $Ext) {
    get-childitem -Path "$Source" -Recurse |  
        Where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays($SetTime) -and $_.name -like "$Ext"} | 
            Move-item -destination "$Temp\Backup-$Date" | 
                Compress-Archive -Path "$Temp\Backup-$Date"  -DestinationPath "$Nas\Backup-$date.Zip"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bsh
$Date = Get-Date -UFormat %d-%m-%Y
$Source = 'C:\Source\'
$Temp = 'C:\Backup-Temp\'
$Nas = 'D:\Destination\'
$Ext = "*.zip","*.rar"
$SetTime = '-5'
$LogFileFullName = 'c:\tmp\log.txt'

function Write-Log([string]$msg){
    Out-File -FilePath $LogFileFullName -InputObject "$([DateTime]::Now): $msg" -Append 
}

New-Item -Path $Temp -Name "Backup-$Date" -ItemType "directory"

Foreach ($Ext in $Ext) {
    get-childitem -Path "$Source" -Recurse |  
        Where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays($SetTime) -and $_.name -like "$Ext"} | 
            ForEach-Object {
                Move-item $_.FullName -destination "$Temp\Backup-$Date" | 
                Compress-Archive -Path "$Temp\Backup-$Date"  -DestinationPath "$Nas\Backup-$date.Zip"
                Write-Log $_.FullName
            }
}
```

Comment: I have tried it, and it is the way I want, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add the following to your chain of piped commands:

```
Add-Content $logfile "$_.name`n"
```

where $logfile is set to a static filename prior.

I may be old-fashioned, but having so many commands in one chain is prone to failure.  It would be more resilient to break-up the chain so that you can include some error checking along the way.

A better but less desirable option would be to put your chain within a try/catch block.

Best of luck.